# How to use the output of a Keras functional-API model as input into another model

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I trained a base functional-API Keras model and now I want to re-use its output as input into a new model, while re-using its weights as well. On the new model I want to add one more input and multiply it with the output of the base model. 
So in the new model I want to have two inputs (including the one of the base model + the new added one) and a new output consisting of element-wise multiplication of the base model output with the new input.

The base model looks as this:

> Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   input_1 (InputLayer)         (None, 30, 1)             0
>   _________________________________________________________________ lstm_1 (LSTM)                (None, 64)                16896
>   _________________________________________________________________ dropout_1 (Dropout)          (None, 64)                0
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_1 (Dense)              (None, 96)                6240
>   _________________________________________________________________ dropout_2 (Dropout)          (None, 96)                0
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 30)                2910

And the  code I tried (but not working) is:

```
newModel = baseModel

base_output = baseModel.get_layer('dense_2').output
input_2 = Input(shape=(n_steps_in, n_features))

multiply = Multiply()([base_output,input_2])

new_output = Dense(30)(multiply)

newModel = Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2], outputs=new_output)

newModel.summary()
```

I receive the error:  "TypeError: Input layers to a `Model` must be `InputLayer` objects. Received inputs: [, ]. Input 0 (0-based) originates from layer type `Dense`.". Any advice on what I am missing? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

IN the line

```
newModel = Model(inputs=[input_1,input_2], outputs=new_output)
```

you have "input_1" where have you defined it. The error is because this varaible is undefined

As per you case you should use

```
input_1=baseModel.input
```

Comment: I want to have two inputs in the new model (the initial input of the base model:input_1 + the new defined input_2.

Comment: use input_1=baseModel.input

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the input from your baseModel.
Try:

```
base_input = baseModel.input
base_output = baseModel.get_layer('dense_2').output
input_2 = Input(shape=(n_steps_in, n_features))

multiply = Multiply()([base_output,input_2])

new_output = Dense(30)(multiply)

newModel = Model(inputs=[base_input, input_2], outputs=new_output)

newModel.summary()
```